# Personal apt-get download server

Tags: server, apt, repository

Disclaimer: Please read complete question before marking duplicate.

I am thinking to setup a server on our college's internal network, which can host some very common apt-get packages. As there are many Ubuntu users in my college, it would save us and even other Ubuntu servers some bandwith.

What I want is that I setup a server similar to those listed in the "Download From" in the software sources. If a person tries apt-get install , Ubuntu should go to my personal server, if it finds the package there, fetch from there else go to some alternate server.

Is it possible? And how can I go about this?

Thank You

Comment: I understand that you explicitly do not want to use a caching proxy, even it that would give you optimal performance in terms of network usage? The duplicate does not exclude proxies, but there are other answers that apply to your question. Read completely, will mark as duplicate.